# How to change the path of data during database restore + SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to restore a big database in SQL Server 2008 R2. The database is about 700GB in size. My SQL Server is installed in C drive which has only 100GB of space left in it. I have the .bak file on the D drive from which I need to restore the database. Is there a way I can restore this database without increasing the space on C drive? (The D drive has 5TB of space and I would want SQL Server to access/place the data from/on D drive)

Any input will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the path for all data and log files in the second tab[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It seems to work i.e. the database is getting restored right now. Do you think I will face performance issues if I have different databases lying around on various disks on the computer?

Comment: If the drive you are restoring it onto is slow, then yes.  Otherwise no, no problems at all.  My SQL Server is installed on my C: drive and I have data drives D:, E: and G:.  Some Dbs I have split over 3 drives to help improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the data files using the move command

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [{DBName}] 
FROM  DISK = N'{PathToBakFile}' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'{DataFileLogicalName}' 
    TO N'{NewPath}',  
MOVE N'{LogFileLogicalName}' 
    TO N'{NewPath}'
GO
```